# How to use $db from another .php to another .php's class using OOP?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

I am new to OOP PHP, and I've been working with procedural API since I've started Web Development so I'm having a hard time migrating to OOP.

so let's say I have this four `.php` file and structures below.

> connection.db.php

```
<?php
    define("DB_HOST", "127.0.0.1");
    define("DB_USER", "root");
    define("DB_PASS", "");
    define("DB_NAME", "sample_db");

    $db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

    echo (!$db->connect_error) ? NULL : die("<pre>Unable to connect to the MySQL Server -> $db->connect_error</pre>");
?>
```

> sampleclass.class.php

```
<?php
    public $db;

    class MySQLqueries {
        public function samplefunction($queryString) {
            $sqlQry = mysqli->query($queryString);

            return ($sqlQry) ? "<pre>Query Executed Successfully</pre>" : die("<pre>An error occured -> $db->error</pre>");
        }
    }
?>
```

> includes.inc.php

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Manila");

    require 'connection.db.php';
    require 'sampleclass.class.php';
?>
```

> index.php

```
<?php
    require 'includes.inc.php';

    $todo = new MySQLqueries;
    echo $todo->samplefunction("SELECT `sample_column` FROM `sample_table` WHERE `sample_column` = 'sample_value';");
?>
```

As you may or may have not noticed, my problem is how to use the `$db` from `connection.db.php` in the `samplefunction` of `sampleclass.class.php`

You may ask me, why not create a `__construct()` method in sampleclass.class.php and just move the "$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);" there ?. well if I'm to do this, all other classes will have to have it's own `constructor` and `$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);` declared there right?

With `$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);` on the `connection.db.php` I assume that I can reuse it versatile-ly.

You see I've declared a `public $db;` in `sampleclass.class.php` but I don't know what's next. If someone can help me dearly, then I would be a lot grateful.

PS: I've already consulted Dr. Google Ph.D. regarding this matter, and I only got tons of articles or video tutorials showing how to use and do OOP PHP-MySQLi Programming but without using classes and methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd be best to create a `DB` class or harnessing an already created one to achieve what you're trying to do.

The usual flow for things like this is call [Lazy Loading/Dependency Injection](http://php-di.org/doc/lazy-injection.html). Where you're passing the required objects into the class.

<sup>*If you choose this path, I suggest that you read up on Dependency Injection, as many things do, it has pros AND cons but is essential in OOP.*</sup>

#### [As Ben Stated in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34756785/oop-php-how-to-use-db-from-another-php-to-another-phps-class/34756890?noredirect=1#comment57259723_34756890):

> Dependency injection is a key principle in OOP. I'd like to add that
>   if you are serious about OOP you should also look into [autoloaders in
>   general](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php), [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) and [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

A side not on the above mentioned, you'd be best to look at [**PHPTheRightWay**](http://www.phptherightway.com/), they list a **lot** of stuff, including [Dependency Injection](http://www.phptherightway.com/#dependency_injection).

You'll end up creating something like. It'd be better if you followed this example to understand how it works:

```
Class DB {

    function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $db) { 
        return $this->connect($host, $user, $pass, $db); 
    }

    function connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) {
        //..connect and all.
    }

    //...the rest of your functions/class...
}
```

<sup>*You can construct this anyway you please. Or just make the `mysqli` object accessible, allowing you to call it.*</sup>

Now we get to the fun stuff. Actually injecting it into your class;

```
Class Foo {

    $private $db;

    // your construct method here will ONLY except a `DB` class instance/object as $db. 
    // Try it with anything else and learn from the errors to understand what I mean.
    function __construct(DB $db){
        $this->db = $db;
    }

}

$db = new DB($host, $user, $pass, $db);
// you can error check it here

$foo = new Foo($db);// inject the $db object.
```

---

If you just want to share the resource, you could harness `global`, **but it is strongly discouraged**.

```
include('connection.db.php');

class MySQLqueries {
        public function samplefunction($queryString) {
            global $db;
            $sqlQry = mysqli->query($queryString);

            return ($sqlQry) ? "<pre>Query Executed Successfully</pre>" : die("<pre>An error occured -> $db->error</pre>");
        }
}
```

<sup>*If you chose this path, you'd be best to assign the `global` instance of `$db` to an internal class variable, like `$this->db`.*</sup>

Comment: +1 Dependency injection is a key principle in OOP. I'd like to add that if you are serious about OOP you should also look into [autoloaders in general](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php), [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) and [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

Comment: @BenHarold Thanks for the links, I'll add them to the answer!

Comment: thanks guys. although im having a hard time to absord this things as i'm really new to OOP. what your trying to say is i'm better off creating a DB Class in my connection.db.php and injecting it on other classes right ?

Comment: @TheQuestioner You're better following a standard. And if you're going down the OOP path, it makes absolute sense to have a Database class that handles any and all interaction with the data. This class will essentially be your [DAO (Data Access Object)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object). It keeps all interaction uniform and should be learnt before undertaking major projects. You should always separate your data access layer from your application. (*Think of it as the pin (DAO) to your bank account (Database with data).*)

Comment: sorry. i almost forgot. :)

Answer (score 5):

As you're alread using objects, you probably should also go to a OOP (Object Oriented Programing) implementation.

So, you may put your `$db` variable as a static variable in the *sampleclass.class.php* file, as in:

```
class MysqlConn
{
    public static $db;
}
```

Like that you instantiate the mysqli object using this code:

```
MysqlConn::$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```

Even better, you could create a method to instantiate the $db connection, initialize the variables in that class:

```
<?php
class MysqlConn
{
    protected
        static $DB_HOST = "127.0.0.1",
        static $DB_USER = "root",
        static $DB_PASS = "",
        static $DB_NAME = "sample_db";

    protected static $db;

    public static function getDB()
    {
        if (!isset(self::$db) {
            self::$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

            if ($db->connect_error) {
                die("<pre>Unable to connect to the MySQL Server -> $db->connect_error</pre>");
            }
        }
        return self::$db;
    }
}

MysqlConn::getDB();
```

In *index.php*, you may get the db instance with the following code, not reconnecting every time:

```
$db = MysqlConn::getDB();
```

Comment: this is kinda good. but also im having trouble absorbing it. thanks :)

Comment: Haven't tested my approach, which is closer to what you have, but @darren 's answer is far better, anyway.
Also, he replied while I was writing. ;)

Comment: You get my vote too @NunoPereira, we're both covering the same thing here :) You just went the singleton method ! Good answer!

Answer (score 0):

> my problem is how to use the $db from connection.db.php in the
>   samplefunction of sampleclass.class.php

You can use global in your case just incluce or require `connection.db.php` then use `global` in php.

Something like this might help you

```
   require_once 'connection.db.php';

        class MySQLqueries {
                public function samplefunction($queryString) {
                    global $db;
                    //You can now use $db variable as you want
                    print_r($db);
                    $sqlQry = mysqli->query($queryString);

                    return ($sqlQry) ? "<pre>Query Executed Successfully</pre>" : die("<pre>An error occured -> $db->error</pre>");
                }
        }
```

Comment: The `global` here rather reduces the portability of the class - perhaps `$db` would be best sent in a constructor?

Comment: @halfer yes I think of that also but OP's question is `How to use $db from another .php to another .php's class using OOP?` How would you answer it directly?In my understanding passing it to the constructor or creating another class for database and injecting it to another class is not using the `$db` variable it is passing the `$db` variable.